# Is there a free Django hosting service out there?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I would like to put my Django web-site online. Is it possible to do so for free?

Answer (score 2):

I used [alwaysdata](https://www.alwaysdata.com/) to upload my site, its very easy to use,

1. Host modern languages
2. Simple & intuitive administration panel
3. Responsive and high-tech support
4. Rich in features

try this one!

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps supports Django, although there are slight differences that you will have to edit in your app. But (i believe) that it is free.

Other than that, you will probably have to pay. Webfaction is a really good django host that is fairly inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [BitNami Django](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) AMI together with Amazon free tier (which gives you 1 Micro instance for free). Should we ok for development or light usage server. Disclaimer, I am part of the BitNami project, but hey, it is free :)

Answer (score 1):

check out http://freedjangohosting.com
there is updated list in this site shows all fre django web hosts available out there